# Pull all jpg's from a folder into a PHP array?

Tags: php

I want to simply pull all the JPG files from a specific folder (on MY server) into an array. I figure it would look something like this. My logic here is that I'd have a folder with images I want in a gallery so I could just upload images with an FTP and they would just show up. Is this a good idea?

```
$dir = 'www.example.com/folder1/';

$images_array = SOMEFUNCTION($dir);

foreach ($images_array) as $v){
echo '<img src="'.$dir.$v.'" />";
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory/37237486#37237486

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[glob()](http://php.net/glob) would work well here:

```
$images_array = glob($dir.'*.jpg');
```

As Zarel commented, you'd have to do a string replacement on the files in the list, as `glob()` will give you the file path in the system, which won't be a direct URL.  Chop off the directory prefix and replace it with a URL prefix using `str_replace()` when you're outputting links.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to use relative paths or internal paths... `$dir = 'www.example.com/anything'` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [directory iterator](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) from Standart PHP Library