# Read File Names From folder Only Keep Files with .iso extention

Tags: php

I have a script that gets a string from a config file and based on that string grabs the file names of a folder.

I now only need the iso files. Not sure if the best way is to check for the .iso string or is there another method?

```
<?php
    // Grab the contents of the "current.conf" file, removing any linebreaks.
    $dirPath = trim(file_get_contents('current.conf')).'/';

    $fileList = scandir($dirPath);

    if(is_array($fileList)) {
        foreach($fileList as $file) {
//could replace the below if statement to only proceed if the .iso string is present. But I am worried there could be issues with this.


         if ($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != "index.php")
{

            echo "<br/><a href='". $dirPath.$file."'>" .$file."</a>\n";
    }
        } 
    }
    else echo $dirPath.' cound not be scanned.';
?>
```

Comment: $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); returns 'iso'  you could key off of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull all jpg's from a folder into a PHP array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217744/pull-all-jpgs-from-a-folder-into-a-php-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need the files with an extension of .iso, then why not use:

[glob($dirPath.'/*.iso');](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

rather than scandir()

Comment: For some reason I am not seeing the files in my array. I tried using just the full path with out the variable  $fileList = glob("http://www.website/2.1-2674/*");

echo count($fileList);

Comment: Do the filenames begin with "2.1-2674" or is "2.1-2674" a directory, in which case you should be using $fileList = glob("website/2.1-2674/*");

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    if(is_array($fileList)) {
        foreach($fileList as $file) {

            $fileSplode = explode('.',$file); //split by '.'
            //this means that u now have an array with the 1st element being the
            //filename and the 2nd being the extension

            echo (isset($fileSplode[1]) && $fileSplode[1]=='iso')?
                    "<br/><a href='". $dirPath.$file."'>" .$file."</a>\n":'');
        } 
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with just doing `substr($file, -4, 4) == '.iso'`? For a fixed file extension, there's no need to do explodes and array manipulation.

Comment: pathinfo() with the PATHINFO_EXTENSION qualifier would be cleaner than using explode() or substr()

Comment: @Marc B, also i dont think that is accounting for the `.` and `..` cases

Comment: Does it matter? The OP's looking for a file. `.` and `..` would never produce '.iso' as a substring so the loop would just keep on trucking. Besides, doing Mark baker's `glob()` call is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in an OOP style you could use:

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dirPath) as $fileInfo) {
   if($fileInfo->getExtension() == 'iso') {
      // do something with it
   }
}

?>
```